# Pivot pandas dataframe based on selected column

Tags: python, pandas

How can the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'car':['BMW','BMW','VW','VW'],'color':['red','blue','red','blue'],'count':[1,2,4,8]})
df

    car    color  count
0   BMW     red     1
1   BMW     blue    2
2   VW      red     4
3   VW      blue    8
```

be transformed to

```
    car     red    blue
0   BMW      1      2
1   VW       4      8
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects):

```
In [9]: df.pivot(index='car', columns='color', values='count').reset_index()
Out[9]: 
color  car  blue  red
0      BMW     2    1
1       VW     8    4
```

If there are multiple rows with the same (car, color) combination, then use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/reshaping.html#pivot-tables) to specify how you wish to aggregate the `count`s:

```
In [7]: df.pivot_table(index='car', columns='color', values='count', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
Out[7]: 
color  car  blue  red
0      BMW     2    1
1       VW     8    4
```

Comment: add `df.columns.name = None` if you want to get rid of the color tag